# croppie - outWHeight is not defined

Tags: jquery, croppie

I'm using Croppie with bootstrap modal like [this](https://codepen.io/tnrnz/pen/KNKLbN) but I get the following error in console of browser, this means that when I click on the Crop button, the error goes below:
ReferenceError: outWHeight is not defined
This is my **Js** Code(While you can find the full code in the *CodePen* link):

```
var $uploadCrop,
        tempFilename,
        rawImg,
        imageId;
        function readFile(input) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
              var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $('.upload-demo').addClass('ready');
                    $('#cropImagePop').modal('show');
                    rawImg = e.target.result;
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
            else {
                swal("Sorry - you're browser doesn't support the FileReader API");
            }
        }

        $uploadCrop = $('#upload-demo').croppie({
            viewport: {
                width: 250,
                height: 250,
            },
            enforceBoundary: false,
            enableExif: true
        });
        $('#cropImagePop').on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
            // alert('Shown pop');
            $uploadCrop.croppie('bind', {
                url: rawImg
            }).then(function(){
                console.log('jQuery bind complete');
            });
        });

        $('.item-img').on('change', function () { imageId = $(this).data('id'); tempFilename = $(this).val();
                                                                                         $('#cancelCropBtn').data('id', imageId); readFile(this); });
        $('#cropImageBtn').on('click', function (ev) {
            $uploadCrop.croppie('result', {
                type: 'base64',
                format: 'jpeg',
                size: {width: 1000, height: 1000}
            }).then(function (resp) {
                $('#item-img-output').attr('src', resp);
                $('#cropImagePop').modal('hide');
            });
        });
```

Comment: I cant reproduce the error

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Error dose not in codepen. When I use the code on my site, I get an error ReferenceError: outWHeight is not defined

Comment: I do not make any changes in the code!

Comment: It must be related to some other code you have since your not using `outWHeight` in the snippet

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I tested the error. I deleted other libraries, but failed.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is no problem, and update all libraries used in the project. Also, use the following library of Croppie, that is, replace it:

https://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/croppie.js

Comment: Thanks, my problem was solved by your method. What was the problem?

Comment: @HosseinKaraji There is a bug in your old library of croppie. The problem is fixed by updating the new library, always use the latest library to update.